# distribute value to all rows while updating table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table structure like `tblCustData`

```
ID    UserID    Fee FeePaid
 1      12      150   0
 2      12      100   0
 3      12      50    0
```

And value to be update in `FeePaid` Column such that if i have value in `@Amt` variable in `200` Then it should update **any** two rows

Output should be like

```
ID    UserID    Fee FeePaid
1      12       150   150
2      12       100   50
3      12       50    0
```

`FeePaid` should not be grater than `Fee` Column But if i pass `350` in `@Amt` variable it should produce output like

```
ID    UserID    Fee FeePaid
1       12      150   200
2       12      100   100
3       12      50    50
```

**Only if `@Amt` is exceeding the total value in `Fee` column**

I can not think beyond this query

```
Update tblCustData
Set FeePaid=@Amt
Where UserID=12
```

Comment: Does order matter, i.e. in first example, could it pay off the 50 and 100 rows, and 50 of the 150 row? Or is it that it must start with the greatest fee line?

Comment: should the row with the highest [fee] always have it's [feepaid] allocated from @Amt first?  if not does the order matter?

Comment: Is there any KEY (ID) unique field in this table?

Comment: @Sean Order does not matter

Comment: @valex : YES there is primary key column named `Code` in this table, but how does that help ? i guess i can update on based on `UserID` column

Comment: @JamieA : As of now order not required

Comment: @SagarDumbre It helps if we need to handle two rows with the same Fee amount for example.

Comment: @valex : question edited

Comment: Starting from 2012 and on, there are `lag()` / `lead()` functions, so this can be solved in a single query using documented features. On 2008, however, cursor is your best bet. There is an undocumented single-query way, yes, but I will not mention it here because MSFT may change this behaviour at will.

Comment: @Ennor can u provide answer using `CURSOR`

Comment: @SagarDumbre Looks like you already have one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First with CTE syntax we prepare a table with sums distribution and then using unique field `Code` update the main table using CASE to handle all possible ways (including first row with remainder).

```
Declare @Amt int;
SET @Amt=250;


with T as 
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Fee desc) as rn, *
   FROM tblCustData WHERE UserId=12
)  
,T2 as 
(
   SELECT *,
          ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Fee-FeePaid) FROM T WHERE T1.RN<RN),0) as PrevSum 
   FROM T as T1
 )

UPDATE
    A
SET A.FeePaid = A.FeePaid+ CASE WHEN (B.PrevSum+B.Fee-B.FeePaid<=@Amt) 
                                     AND (B.RN<>1) 
                                        THEN B.Fee-B.FeePaid
                     WHEN (B.PrevSum+B.Fee-B.FeePaid<=@Amt) AND (B.RN=1) 
                                        THEN @Amt-B.PrevSum
                     WHEN B.PrevSum>=@Amt 
                                        THEN 0                 
                     WHEN B.PrevSum+B.Fee-B.FeePaid>@Amt 
                                        THEN @Amt-B.PrevSum
              END
FROM
    tblCustData A
    JOIN T2 B ON A.Code = B.Code
GO
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80a35/1)</kbd>

Comment: This code presumes all FeePaid fields are 0. How would you change it to accommodate several partial payments

Comment: @Valex : It works but only at single execution it does not take previous `FeePaid` Value. It starts from 0 again. It is partial payment kind of system

Comment: @SagarDumbre: I've edit query to handle previous `FeePaid` values. Thanks @Sean

Comment: @valex : i just checked it does not work if i try to do partial payment in more than 2 steps. just check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af43f/3/0

Comment: @valex : take small `amt` value (less than 50) and try to run multiple times

Comment: @SagarDumbre And...? I took @Amt=10 and run update statement 3 times. It's Ok. After first row is over the sum is distributed to the second row and so on. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3de8c/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try ..

```
declare @t table (id int identity, UserId int, Fee money, FeePaid money)

insert into @t (UserID,  Fee, FeePaid)
values
(12,      150,   0)
,(12,      100,   0)
,(12,      50 ,   0)

declare @amt money = 200;   -- change to 400 to test over paid

declare @Fees money;
select @Fees = sum(Fee) from @t;

declare @derivedt table (deid int, id int, UserId int, Fee money, FeePaid money)

insert into @derivedt (deid, id, UserId, Fee, FeePaid)
select row_number() over (order by case when @amt <= @Fees then id else -id end asc), id, UserId, Fee, FeePaid
    from @t
    -- order by case when @amt <= @Fees then id else -id end asc

; with cte(deid, id, UserId, Fee, FeePaid, Remainder)
as
(
    select 0 as deid, 0 as id, 0 as UserId, cast(0.00 as money) as Fee, cast(0.00 as money) as FeePaid , @Amt as Remainder
    from @derivedt
    where id = 1
    union all
    select t.deid, t.id, t.UserId, t.Fee, case when cte.Remainder > t.Fee then t.Fee else cte.Remainder end as FeePaid
        , case when cte.Remainder > t.Fee then cte.Remainder - t.Fee else 0 end as Remainder
    from @derivedt t inner join cte cte on t.deid = (cte.deid + 1)
)

update origt
set FeePaid = det.FeePaid
from @t origt
    inner join
    (
    select cte1.deid, cte1.id, cte1.UserId, cte1.Fee, cte1.FeePaid + ISNULL(cte2.Remainder, 0) as FeePaid
    from cte cte1
        left outer join (select top 1 deid, Remainder from cte order by deid desc) cte2
        on cte1.deid = cte2.deid
    where cte1.deid > 0
    ) det
    on origt.id = det.id

select *
from @t
```

Modified to continuous update of value..

```
    -- Create table once and insert into table once
create table #t (id int identity, UserId int, Fee money, FeePaid money)

insert into #t (UserID,  Fee, FeePaid)
values
(12,      150,   0)
,(12,      100,   0)
,(12,      50 ,   0)

-- ===============================

-- Run multiple times to populate #t table 
declare @amt money = 100;   -- change to 400 to test over paid

declare @Fees money;
select @Fees = sum(Fee - FeePaid) from #t;

declare @derivedt table (deid int, id int, UserId int, Fee money, FeePaid money)

insert into @derivedt (deid, id, UserId, Fee, FeePaid)
select row_number() over (order by case when @amt <= @Fees then id else -id end asc), id, UserId, (Fee - FeePaid) as Fee, FeePaid
    from #t
    -- order by case when @amt <= @Fees then id else -id end asc

; with cte(deid, id, UserId, Fee, FeePaid, Remainder)
as
(
    select 0 as deid, 0 as id, 0 as UserId, cast(0.00 as money) as Fee, cast(0.00 as money) as FeePaid , @Amt as Remainder
    from @derivedt
    where id = 1
    union all
    select t.deid, t.id, t.UserId, t.Fee, case when cte.Remainder >= t.Fee then t.Fee else cte.Remainder end as FeePaid
        , case when cte.Remainder >= t.Fee then cte.Remainder - t.Fee else 0 end as Remainder
    from @derivedt t inner join cte cte on t.deid = (cte.deid + 1)
)


update origt
set FeePaid = origt.FeePaid + det.FeePaid
from #t origt
    inner join
    (
    select cte1.deid, cte1.id, cte1.UserId, cte1.Fee, cte1.FeePaid + ISNULL(cte2.Remainder, 0) as FeePaid, cte1.Remainder
    from cte cte1
        left outer join (select top 1 deid, Remainder from cte order by deid desc) cte2
        on cte1.deid = cte2.deid
    where cte1.deid > 0
    ) det
    on origt.id = det.id

select *
from #t


-- Drop temp table after
-- drop table #t
```

Comment: same problem, it does not specify partial payment. It all over starts from 0 again

Comment: @SagarDumbre .. Edit answer to include code to continuous running total

Answer (score -2):

Apart from your code, I added an identity column to your table. See the code.

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),USERID INT, FEE INT, FEEPAID INT)
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES (12,150,0),(12,100,0),(12,50,0)

DECLARE @AMOUNT INT = 230,
        @AMOUNTNEW INT = 0,
        @B INT = 1,
        @S INT = 1,@E INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TAB)

WHILE   @S <= @E
BEGIN
    UPDATE  LU
    SET     LU.FEEPAID = CASE WHEN @AMOUNT >= FEE THEN FEE ELSE @AMOUNT END
    FROM    @TAB LU
    WHERE   LU.ID = @S

    SET     @AMOUNT = @AMOUNT - (SELECT FEE FROM @TAB WHERE ID = @S)
    IF      @AMOUNT <= 0  
            SET @S = @E

    SET     @S = @S + 1

END

SELECT * FROM @TAB
```

**Result:**

[image]

I hope the idea is clear, we can work from here.

Comment: `@S <= @E` Total wrong assumption. Why you are comparing total no. of records with ID column value. i can have id column value as `122` and count is `4`

Comment: I hope, we will be managing only one userId at a time. Bring all the records of a single userId to a temp table. Run the above sql, and Update back to the main table.